# Seeking Trimble GGF Geoid File Format Specification?

Tags: trimble, geoid, binary

I want to generate Trimble GGF Geoid files from my software.

Can anyone provide me with a format specification for the binary ggf files used by Trimble?

I found a basic description on the [OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Trimble_GGF):

```
ORIGIN: top left
0 0 TNL GRID FILE\0 XXX\0*
1 0 TNL GRID FILE
0x30 8-> ymin (°) (Min Latitude in decimal degrees)
0x38 8-> ymax (°) (Max Latitude in decimal degrees)
0x40 8-> xmin (°) (Min Longitude in decimal degrees)
0x48 8-> xmax (°) (Max Longitude in decimal degrees)
0x50 8-> dy (°)    (Step size for latitudes, in decimal degrees)
0x58 8-> dx (°)  (Step size for longitudes, in decimal degrees)
0x60 4->  (vNY, nrows)
0x64 4->  (vNX, ncols)
       North Pole
       South Pole
       Missing Value (nodata)
       Scale
       Flags*
0x92+ data*
```

But some information is missing:

- How is the data between 0x68 and 0x92 supposed to look?
- How are the geoid heigth's supposes to be stored in the data* section?

  - Column-wise?
  - Row-wise?
  - South-West to North-East or the other way around?

Comment: Could you mafe it? im going crazy searching for an application to create local geoids, i can do it for leica but not for trimble and topcon

Comment: Yes, I was able to create a python script to generate ggf files. I can post it on monday, when I am back at the office.

Answer (score 0):

As requested by Joan Gonzalez:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from dms import *
import copy
import struct
import binascii

import numpy as np

def dms2decdeg(grad,min,sek):
    grad=float(grad)
    min=float(min)
    sek=float(sek)
    return (grad + (min * 1/60) + (sek * 1/60 * 1/60))

def calculateRowsCols(grid_west_start,grid_south_start,grid_east_end,grid_north_end,gridwidth,gridheight):
    my_grid_west_start = copy.deepcopy(grid_west_start)
    my_grid_south_start = copy.deepcopy(grid_south_start)
    rows=0
    cols=0
    while my_grid_west_start.to_dd()<grid_east_end.to_dd():
        my_grid_west_start.add(0,0,gridwidth)
        cols+=1
    while my_grid_south_start.to_dd()<grid_north_end.to_dd():
        my_grid_south_start.add(0,0,gridheight)
        rows+=1
    return rows,cols

gridwidth_seconds = 30.0
gridheight_seconds = 30.0

#define Area
grid_west_start = dms(15.329297)
grid_east_end = dms(15.411587)
grid_south_start = dms(41.702492)
grid_north_end = dms(41.763123)

zeilen,spalten = calculateRowsCols(grid_west_start,grid_south_start,grid_east_end,grid_north_end,gridwidth_seconds,gridheight_seconds)
print "Zeilen: ",zeilen," Spalten: ",spalten

print "south: " + str(grid_south_start.to_dd()) + " " + str(dms2decdeg(50,36,30))


#Undulations in this Grid are stored from south to north (result from other workflow...)
#-> First row in grid is southernmost row
undulationen = np.empty([zeilen, spalten])
zeilen_akt=0
while zeilen_akt<zeilen:
    #GET UNDULATIONS FROM SOMEWHERE

print "first ",undulationen[0,0]," ",undulationen[0,-1]
print "last  ",undulationen[-1,0]," ",undulationen[-1,-1]

'''
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Trimble_GGF

ORIGIN: top left
0 0 TNL GRID FILE\0 XXX\0*
1 0 TNL GRID FILE
0x30 8-> ymin (°) (Min Latitude in decimal degrees)
0x38 8-> ymax (°) (Max Latitude in decimal degrees)
0x40 8-> xmin (°) (Min Longitude in decimal degrees)
0x48 8-> xmax (°) (Max Longitude in decimal degrees)
0x50 8-> dy (°)    (Step size for latitudes, in decimal degrees)
0x58 8-> dx (°)  (Step size for longitudes, in decimal degrees)
0x60 4->  (vNY, nrows)
0x64 4->  (vNX, ncols)
       North Pole <-- dec: 68
       South Pole
       Missing Value (nodata)
       Scale
       Flags*
0x92+ data*    <-- dec: 146

Data is stored as 4byte LE floats, the only known exception is OSU91.GGF (2byte integer format, probably some bit is set in the flags)
'''
with open("test.ggf", "wb") as f:
    print "#########GGF###########"

    for _ in range(48):
        f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<c', '#')))

    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(grid_south_start.to_dd())))) #0x30 8-> ymin (°) (Min Latitude in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(grid_north_end.to_dd())))) #0x38 8-> ymax (°) (Max Latitude in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(grid_west_start.to_dd())))) #0x40 8-> xmin (°) (Min Longitude in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(grid_east_end.to_dd())))) #0x48 8-> xmax (°) (Max Longitude in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(dms2decdeg(0,0,gridheight_seconds))))) #0x50 8-> dy (°)    (Step size for latitudes, in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<d', float(dms2decdeg(0,0,gridwidth_seconds))))) #0x58 8-> dx (°)  (Step size for longitudes, in decimal degrees)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<i', int(zeilen)))) #0x60 4->  (vNY, nrows)
    f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<i', int(spalten)))) #0x64 4->  (vNX, ncols)

    #copy flags header from arbitrary existing 'official' ggf.
    with open("ggf_flags_header.ggf", "rb") as h:
        for _ in range((42)):
            f.write(h.read(1))

    zeilen_akt=0

    #Undulations in GGF File are written from north to south and west to east
    while zeilen_akt<zeilen:

        spalten_akt=0
        while spalten_akt<spalten:

            und = undulationen[zeilen-zeilen_akt-1,spalten_akt]
            f.write(bytearray(struct.pack('<f', float(und))))

            spalten_akt+=1
        zeilen_akt+=1
```

I cheated a little bit because I only copied the headers between 0x68 and 0x92 from existing files. I still have no Idea what the headers in this area are supposed to do.

For the script to run, you need to define the grid area (rows 34-37) and provide the undulation values (row 50).

Answer (score 0):

Messing around with the utility gives the following:

```
0x68 8-> N pole Value
0x70 8-> S pole value
0x78 8-> Missing Value
0x80 8->Multiplier (If zero is a multiplier of 1)
```

The flags I can't say for sure as I can only go off examples. The important one for reading in is to check 0x8D.

```
0x88 1-> interpolation mode (2=bilinear, 3=biquadratic, 4=bispline)
0x8A most significant bit-> 1=WGS84, 0=local ellipsoid (I've seen the other bits used but no not whatfor)
0x8C also changes with the interpolation mode (2=bilinear, 8=biquadratic, 4=bispline)
0x8D 1->Data format (examples I've seen are 2=int16,8=float32 but I know int8, int32, float64 & float80 are supported)
```

There should also be fields for whether the file contains lat shifts, long shifts &/| geoid separations as well as a field for the number of fields per grid cell (I'm guessing this is 0x8F being the only field/bit I've seen to be invariant at 1)

As you've noted the data is NW to SE with an outer iteration over the latitude and an inner over the longitude.